# JScrollPane for multiple labels

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlabel

I am working on a program that has a flow layout, inside are a set of labels and because there are so many they do not all display. Is there anyway to add a scroll pane to scroll through all of these labels horizontally?

```
JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel();
     mainpanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainpanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        pane.add(mainpanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel rightpanel = new JPanel();
        rightpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            rightpanel.add(new JLabel("Label " + i));
        }
        mainpanel.add(new JLabel("Left label"));
        mainpanel.add(new JScrollPane(rightpanel));
```

Comment: You say in the comments that you get a Null Pointer Exception. What line is this from? Where do you define `pane` in the above code? Try to always provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest ot use [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) or [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) with one `Column` or `Row` (depends or direction), Object in the `JList` or `JTable` is `JLabel/JComponent` by default

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your question really is, since you already know you need to use a `JScrollPane`. How about:

```
public class ScrollLabels
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Labels");

        JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel();
        mainpanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainpanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        frame.add(mainpanel);

        JPanel rightpanel = new JPanel();
        rightpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            rightpanel.add(new JLabel("Label " + i));
        }
        mainpanel.add(new JLabel("Left label"));
        mainpanel.add(new JScrollPane(rightpanel));
        frame.setSize(500, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you DNA, but what if I wanted a label on the left, lets say: "Name" and a bunch of labels on the right and for the scroll pane to scroll only the labels on the right.

Comment: Then you would need to add the label and the scrollpane to another container, and choose a layout manager (probably BoxLayout) to lay them out left and right.

Comment: Could you show me an example as I have tried for more than 3 hours and I just can't get it working.

Comment: Please check my original post which iv just edited. It is what i am trying to do but am receiving a null pointer error.